# Using Material-UI's Autocomplete component with Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

Currently trying to use Material UI's [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component with Formik. So far things like text fields and traditional selects from Material-UI play very nice with Formik. Implementing Autocomplete is not the case. Formik's onChange handler doesn't seem to update the value for my `city_id`. I know Autocomplete is still not apart of Material-UI's core library but was still seeing if something like this was a possibility at the moment.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import { cities } from '../data/cities';

import "./styles.css";

const initialValues = {
  city_id: '',
};

const submit = params => {
  alert(`Value for city_id is: ${params.city_id}`);
};

function App() {
  return (
     <Formik
      initialValues={ initialValues }
      onSubmit={ submit }
    >
      {({
        handleChange,
        values,
      }) => (
        <Form>
          <Autocomplete
            id="city_id"
            name="city_id"
            options={ cities }
            groupBy={ option => option.state }
            getOptionLabel={ option => option.name }
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={params => (
              <TextField
                { ...params }
                onChange={ handleChange }
                margin="normal"
                label="Cities"
                fullWidth
                value={ values.city_id }
              />
            )}
          />

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit angry-goldstine-8offj]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your problem is that `handleChange` won't work the way you are doing.

If you take a look at the [handleChange docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeevent-any-void):

> General input change event handler. This will update the values[key] where key is the event-emitting input's name attribute. If the name attribute is not present, handleChange will look for an input's id attribute. Note: "input" here means all HTML inputs.

Which should work fine, but the problem is that the `TextField` inside `Autocomplete` will only trigger `handleChange` when you type something on it, and the value will be the text, not the `id` or other property you want, so you need to move `handleChange` to the `Autocomplete`.

And there is another problem, you can't use `handleChange` in the `Autocomplete` because it doesn't references the input you want and it also have different parameters from the normal `onChange` of the `input`, as you can see in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props).

> `onChange`
>   func
>   Callback fired when the value changes.
>     Signature:
>     `function(event: object, value: any) => void`
>     `event`: The event source of the callback
>     `value`: null

So what you need to do is use `setFieldValue` and pass it to `Autocomplete` like

```
onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue("city_id", value)}
```

You need to pass the name of your field and what value you want to get.

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-albattani-yk9z4)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @CarlEdwards You are welcome, please consider upvoting, thanks!

Comment: Done for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Also please consider upvoting my question if it has deemed noteworthy.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again!

Comment: As an addition there were 8 patches on the Autocomplete component in material 4.7.1 so if anyone is still having issues after following Vencovsky's spot on explanation this may be why.

Comment: Although this works, reset option does not work. See this here https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-moon-shlr5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Vencovsky can you add yup to your example? I would like to know how you make this field required. I put this parameter as string required but I have problem to set the value as you put because it's string in my case and not object as you set

Answer (score 12):

@vencovsky has provided the correct answer that is still working for me with Material UI 14.10.1.

I'm adding a bit more to it as I have my field set to `required` in using `Yup` validation.

To get this to work correctly I have the following:
`Yup` config:

```
validationSchema = {
    Yup.object().shape({
        contact: Yup.string().max(255).required('Contact is required'),
    })
}
```

react:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="contact-autocomplete"
    options={contacts}
    getOptionLabel={(contact) => `${contact?.firstName} ${contact?.lastName}`}
    onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue("contact", value?.id || "")}
    onOpen={handleBlur}
    includeInputInList
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            error={Boolean(touched.contact && errors.contact)}
            fullWidth
            helperText={touched.contact && errors.contact}
            label="Contact Person"
            name="contact"
            variant="outlined"
        />
    )}
/>
```

When the user click on the `Autocomplete` element, it fires the `onOpen` which runs the `Formik` `onBlur` and marks the field as touched. If an item is then not picked, Formik `flags` the field and displays the `Contact is required` validation message.

Comment: `onOpen={handleBlur}` displays "Required" error during selection. Using `onBlur={handleBlur}` instead is nicer, as the error is displayed only after selection/clear.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `onChange = {(event, value) => handleChange(value)}` in `Autocomplete` tag as

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import { cities } from '../data/cities';

import "./styles.css";

const [cityId,setCityId]=React.useState({city_id:''});

const handleChange=(value)=>{
  // Here is the value is a selected option label or the new typed value
  setCityId({city_id:value});
}


function App() {
  return (
     <Formik
      initialValues={ cityId }
      onSubmit={() => {
        alert(`Value for city_id is: ${cityId.city_id}`);
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleChange,
        values,
      }) => (
        <Form>
          <Autocomplete
            id="city_id"
            name="city_id"
            options={ cities }
            groupBy={ option => option.state }
            getOptionLabel={ option => option.name }
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            onChange = {(event, value) => handleChange(value)}
            renderInput={params => (
              <TextField
                { ...params }
                onChange={ handleChange }
                margin="normal"
                label="Cities"
                fullWidth
                value={ values.city_id }
              />
            )}
          />

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**If onChange don't work you can use onInputChange as well.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and solved. Sharing my experience

Updating formik values directly on `OnChange` method solved the issue

```
onChange={(event, value) => (formik.values.country = value!)}
```

Here is the full code

Formik settings

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      id: user.id || "",
      name: user.name || "",
      country: user.country,
      email: user.email || "",
      submit: null,
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      email: Yup.string()
        .email("Must be a valid email")
        .max(255)
        .required("Email is required"),
      name: Yup.string().max(255).required("Name is required"),
    }),
    onSubmit: async (values, helpers): Promise<void> => {
      console.log("Updating user...");
      try {
        let userData: UserDetails = {
          id: values.id,
          email: values.email,
          name: values.name,
          country: values.country,
        };
        await userApi.registerUser(userData);
        helpers.setStatus({ success: true });
        helpers.setSubmitting(false);
        toast.success("User updated!");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        toast.error("Something went wrong!");
        helpers.setStatus({ success: false });
        helpers.setErrors({ submit: err.message });
        helpers.setSubmitting(false);
      }
    },
  });
```

Autocomplete

```
            <Autocomplete
                getOptionLabel={(option): string => option.text}
                options={countries}
                value={formik.values.country}
                defaultValue={formik.values.country}
                onChange={(event, value) => (formik.values.country = value!)}
                renderInput={(params): JSX.Element => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    fullWidth
                    label="Country"
                    name="country"
                    error={Boolean(
                      formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country
                    )}
                    helperText={formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                  />
                )}
              />
```