# Material Autocomplete - auto selecting an option when options change. React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am trying to get Material Autocomplete to auto select my initially loaded option, but am having some issues. I'm very new to React and so may be doing something fundamentally wrong, but my code is basically doing this.

```
export default function AsyncPicker({name, formik, initialOptions = []}) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(initialOptions);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOptions(initialOptions);
    },[initialOptions])

   return (
       <Autocomplete
           ....otherProps
           options={options}
           value={{id:formik.values[name]}}
           getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>  option.id === value.id}
       />
   )
}
```

The options are loaded asynchronously when typing, but for the initial option I want to load a single option based on the value of the record.
From a parent component I am rendering the Autocomplete that initially gets a default empty array for its initialOptions. When data is loaded asynchronously for the given record the initialOptions is updated to reflect the value of the record loaded. The options update in the child control and the option renders, but it does not auto select.

getOptionSelected does fire upon the initialOptions being updated and the id of both the option and the value match, so why is it not being selected?

As I said, happy to be told Im doing it completely wrong as had never written a line of react 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return (
       <Autocomplete
           ....otherProps
           options={options}
           value={{id:formik.values[name]}}
           getOptionSelected={(option, value) => formik.setFieldValue(option.id === value.id)}
       />
   )
```

tie the onChange function to formik's setFieldValue function as in this answer?

[Using Material-UI's Autocomplete component with Formik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217658/using-material-uis-autocomplete-component-with-formik)

Comment: No. I am calling setOptions when the initialOptions are first provided (which is the only point it should be selected) and then on subsequent api calls after user input.

Comment: That results in the error: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Im guessing its because setFieldValue causes the component to re-render which results in infinite loop. Also, I dont understand the intent behind that fix, doesnt setFieldValue just set a value to the underlying formik object? Wheras in this case the formik object has its values, the picker has loaded the option, its just that I need to select it